# Can I get the line number of an error in an eval'ed Groovy script?

Tags: groovy

I have a piece of code that is to run a user-provided Groovy script, as follows:

```
def scriptText = <something user entered>
def manager = new ScriptEngineManager()
def engine = manager.getEngineByName('Groovy')

try {
    engine.eval(scriptText)
}
catch (ScriptException e) {
    println 'Script error at line ' + e.getLineNumber() + ', column ' + e.getColumnNumber() + ': ' + e.getMessage()
}
```

If I deliberately put an error in the input script that is supplied, this code will print the following (containing undefined line and column numbers):

```
Script error at line -1, column -1: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: blah for class: Script1
```

I've also tried just calling Eval.me(scriptText), as the calling code is also Groovy, but then I get a large stack trace with the cause of the script error buried inside, as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: blah for class: Script1
Possible solutions: class
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:6)  <---- this is the script error
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:556)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:527)
    at groovy.util.Eval.me(Eval.java:68)
    at groovy.util.Eval.me(Eval.java:51)
    at groovy.util.Eval$me.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.kminnovations.metrics.engine.tester.Testing.parseFile(Testing.groovy:32)
    at com.kminnovations.metrics.engine.tester.Testing$parseFile.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at com.kminnovations.metrics.engine.tester.MetricsEngineTester.main(MetricsEngineTester.groovy:23)
```

Is there a way to execute script text from within a program and get precisely the location of the error in the script, so that I can display it clearly for the user who provided it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still get the line by navigating to the root cause and searching for source like ScriptN.groovy, because `ScriptEngineManager` will automatically generate this name for every executed script.

```
def manager = new ScriptEngineManager()
def engine = manager.getEngineByName('Groovy')

try {
    engine.eval(scriptText)
} catch (javax.script.ScriptException e) {
    def cause = rootCause(e)
    def line = cause.stackTrace.find { 
        it.fileName ==~ /^Script\d+\.groovy$/ 
    }.lineNumber
    println "Line $line: $cause.message"
}

def rootCause(Exception e) {
    Throwable t = e;
    while (t.cause != null) t = t.cause;
    t
}
```

You might want to have more complicated `rootCause` like in apache.commons.ExceptionUtils

Comment: This stops the execution of the groovy. Do we have any other way of capturing the line number without terminating or stopping the execution of the groovy?